# Getting Unsupported token `on` [GraphQL]

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, graphql-kotlin

Issue: We goto 'on' in the query, while build apollo is complaining about the on keyword in the query (*.graphql)

GraphQL query:

```
query TimeLine($inputData: InputData!) {
    getTimeLine(inputData: $inputData) {
        on
        updated
 }
}
```

Error: **Unsupported token `on`**
*(com.apollographql.apollo.compiler.parser.GraphQLDocumentParseException).*

Env: Kotlin,  apolloGraphQLVersion: "1.3.2"

Comment: how are you providing the schema

Comment: I took schema from server and saved it in schema.json. Here is the schema for the `on` field. The schema is fine, as it's working fine for other fields. ```{
              "name": "on",
              "args": [],
              "type": {
                "kind": "NON_NULL",
                "name": null,
                "ofType": {
                  "kind": "SCALAR",
                  "name": "String",
                  "ofType": null
                }
              },
              "isDeprecated": false,
              "deprecationReason": null
            }```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `on` keyword is a reserved keyword in GraphQL.

One of the Type Conditions is `on` NamedType, see [the official spec file of GraphQL](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Type-Conditions).

```
query FragmentTyping {
  profiles(handles: ["zuck", "cocacola"]) {
    handle
    ...userFragment
    ...pageFragment
  }
}

fragment userFragment on User {
  friends {
    count
  }
}

fragment pageFragment on Page {
  likers {
    count
  }
}
```

See the `on` used in `fragment userFragment on User`? Your GraphQL got confused because you are using `on` as a field within the query, while it expects to be a fragment. [Read more about fragments here](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments). Also, a fragment's name can be anything, except for `on`, see the [official spec file](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Language.Fragments).

One way to solve this issue might be to rename the field in your query, but I am not sure if GraphQL will complain about this approach as well:

```
query TimeLine($inputData: InputData!) {
    getTimeLine(inputData: $inputData) {
        dataOn: on
        updated
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. It's giving same error, i.e., Unsupported token `on` ........ dataOn: on

Comment: @Amit Can you change your server part?

Comment: Unfortunately, changing this field name is not a viable option. We need to put some hacks on the client side only. We're a client and server sid eis owned by a different team.